# date comparision with laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, laravel-4.2

I want to fetch records which are older than 2 days.

My current database records for `added_to_cart_at` field is just one row dated `2016-05-01 12:23:23`

I used below code

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify('-2 days');

$formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $formatted_date; // prints 2016-04-29 14:27:42 

    $result = DB::table('cart_reminder')->whereDate('added_to_cart_at','<=',$formatted_date)->get();
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        echo $row->user_email;
    }
```

Ideally above `where` condition should fail and should return 0 records. But it fetches a record. 
**EDITED :**

```
  $result = DB::table('cart_reminder')->whereDate(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateString())->get();
    foreach ($result as $row)
{
    echo $row->user_email;
}
```

it prints error

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereDate(), called in
```

Why?

Comment: I don't think you should use `whereDate()` here, just regular `where()`.

Comment: changed. still it prints email address , and condition gets true

Comment: Given that Laravel dates work nicely with Carbon, have you tried passing in a Carbon object instead of a formatted string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying a column.

`whereDate('added_to_cart_at', $carbon)`